# JNA program function lookup failure

Tags: c++, jna

I'm newbee with JNA programing, the task I want to accomplish is:

1. C++ library exposes functionality to "put" a buffer in to a file and "lookup" a buffer. I compiled a shared object (.so) for this library with the header file providing the function definitions under "extern "C" " to make it C compiler friendly.
2. Test java program to access the buffers.

The code looks like this:

C/C++ code:

```
extern "C"
{
int get(int length, char *buffer);
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int get(int length, char *buffer)
{
    char *newBuff = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        newBuff[i] = 'a';
    }

    memcpy(newBuff, buffer, length);
    delete newBuffer;
    return length;
}
```

java code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class TestJna
{
    public static interface TestNative extends Library
    {
        int get(int length, Memory buffer);
    }
    private static final TestNative lib_ = (TestNative)Native.loadLibrary("libsample.so", TestNative.class);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int length = 1024;
        Memory buffer = new Memory(length);
        int ret = lib_.get(length, buffer);
        System.out.println("ret:" + ret + ":buffer:" + buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

On running the program I get below error message on invocation of "lib.get()" method:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'get': dlsym(0x7f8d08d1e7d0, get): symbol not found

Comment: I've never used JNA, but it looks like it's complaining because you're declaring a function called `get` inside of the `TestNative` interface but never defining it.

Comment: you have missed `[]` in the `delete newBuffer;` statement as it is a pointer to arrar.

Comment: sure, but it the NOT the primary concern while Java code remains the same. Will fix memory leak in C++ anyhow

Comment: Use `nm filename` to see what symbols are exported from the library.

Comment: nm is showing presence of "get" symbol bash-3.2$ nm libsample.so
0000000000000eb0 T __Z3getiPc
                 U __ZdaPv
                 U __Znam
                 U _memcpy
                 U dyld_stub_binder
bash-3.2$ c++filt __Z3getiPc
get(int, char*)

Comment: use `string` not `string.h` as a name for the inclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by modifying code as follows:

```
public static interface TestNative extends Library
    {
        int get(int length, Pointer buffer);
    }
```

Pointer was obtained by:

```
Pointer bfPtr = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(buffer); // buffer points to ByteBuffer allocated as direct NIO buffer.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exported symbol (according to `nm`) is mangled.  You need to add `extern "C"` prior to your function definition in addition to its declaration, i.e.

```
extern "C" get(int length, char* buffer) {
    ...
}
```

The first `extern "C"` syntax you use is typically used for groups of declarations in a header file.  You also must explicitly unmangle the definition.